# what's the equivalent of boto.exception.BotoServerError in boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, boto3

In [boto exceptions.py](https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/develop/boto/exception.py), there is a `class BotoServerError(StandardError)`. However, in [boto3 exceptions.py](https://github.com/boto/boto3/blob/develop/boto3/exceptions.py) it no longer exists. What would be its replacement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Boto3, this is pushed in `botocore`.

[botocore exceptions.py](https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/develop/botocore/exceptions.py)

> class ClientError(Exception):

```
>>> from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
```